# Cannot restore a collection from a zipped bson

Tags: mongodb

I have a `mongorestore` of vesion 3.4.5:

```
$ mongorestore --version
mongorestore version: r3.4.5
git version: 520b8f3092c48d934f0cd78ab5f40fe594f96863
Go version: go1.7
   os: linux
   arch: amd64
   compiler: gc
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

Since I don't have enough disk space on my server so I have to restore my database from a zip file. I try the same command as in the documentation but it gives errors, which seems `mongorestore` ignores the standard input:

```
$ zcat threads.bson.zip | mongorestore --db suomi24 --collection threads --verbose
2017-06-16T23:29:39.377+0300    using write concern: w='1', j=false, fsync=false, wtimeout=0
2017-06-16T23:29:39.377+0300    the --db and --collection args should only be used when restoring from a BSON file. Other uses are deprecated and will not exist in the future; use --nsInclude instead
2017-06-16T23:29:39.378+0300    using default 'dump' directory
2017-06-16T23:29:39.378+0300    see mongorestore --help for usage information
2017-06-16T23:29:39.378+0300    Failed: mongorestore target 'dump' invalid: stat dump: no such file or directory
```

The zip file is ~10GB large so I cannot do

```
$ dump=$(zcat threads.bson.zip);mongorestore --db suomi24 --collection threads < $dump
zsh: fatal error: out of heap memory
```

So what is the correct way?

Comment: maybe you should use the _--archive_ option or _--gzip_

Comment: @calazans So `mongorestore --help` gives an updated documentation which contains the `--gzip` switch. Now `mongorestore --db db --collection collection --gzip threads.bson.zip` gives `Failed: error scanning filesystem: file collection.bson.zip does not have .bson extension`. Strange for me because it seems to be looking for a normal `.bson` file.

Comment: @calazans Oh `mongorestore --gzip` is paired with `mongodump --archive`.  So maybe I should dump the database again.

Comment: One question @ziyuang , how did you get this threads.bson.zip?
If possible you could make another dump like this               `mongodump --archive=threads.bson.gz --gzip --db test`
and than you could use something like this                       
`mongorestore --gzip --archive=threads.bson.gz --db test`.
But i don't know if possible restore from _zip_ file

Comment: @calazans I `mongodump`ed the database into bson and zipped it myself.

Comment: instead of you make a dump directly to bson and zipped because you database is very big, i think if you directly make a dump file compressed its easy to restore it in this other server.Maybe the gzip filed might get smaller than the bson zipped.

Comment: @calazans Yes the combination solves the issue. Thank you. Maybe you can post it as an answer before the question is closed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of you make a dump directly to bson and zipped because you database is very big, i think if you make a dump file compressed its easy to restore it in this other server.
You could make the dump like this:

```
mongodump --archive=threads.bson.gz --gzip --db test
```

and than you could restore like this:

```
mongorestore --gzip --archive=threads.bson.gz --db test
```

.